# How to print hex number in little endian, padded zeroes, and no '0x' in python?

Tags: python, format, hex

I want to write a loop that will print 1 through 50000  in 4B hex number format. However, I need the hex numbers to be in little endian format, display all zeroes up to 4B, and show no '0x' at the beginning.

Example:

The number 50,000 is 0xc350 in hex.

I want to print: 50C30000

This is what I have so far, I just don't know how to add the zeroes to get it to be 4B format:

```
import struct
print hex( struct.unpack( '<H', struct.pack('>H', 50000) ) [0] ) [2:].upper()
#Output is 50C3
```

~Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's assume you've got the part that converts to little-endian working. The part you're asking is how to format a number into a particular string.

That's exactly what the [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) function is for:

```
>>> h = 20675
>>> format(h, '04X')
50C3
```

The full details are in the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language), but briefly:

- `'X'` is a *type* field, meaning "Hex format. Outputs the number in base 16, using upper- case letters for the digits above 9."
- `'4'` is a *width* field, which means anything shorter than 4 characters will be padded.
- `'0'` is a… special case that has no name, apparently, but "Preceding the width field by a zero ('0') character enables sign-aware zero-padding for numeric types. This is equivalent to a fill character of '0' with an alignment type of '='."

---

But let's revisit that first sentence. You *don't* have the byte-swapping right, because you want a 32-bit little-endian number, and you're creating a 16-bit one. That's what `'H'` means. If you want 32 bits, you have to use `'I'`.

And then, of course, you need to change the width from `4` to `8`.

Comment: Given what I already have, I can somehow insert what I have into this format() function?

Comment: @Ian004: Well, my `h` is exactly what you get back from `struct.unpack( '<H', struct.pack('>H', 50000) ) [0]`. Can you figure it out from there?

Comment: Yes, however I believe the 'X' type field is converting it back to standard hex thus nullifying the endian formatting I did. My output is now 000050C3

Comment: The padding of zeroes in format is always to the left of the string. @abarnert is there a way to change the direction? I use ljust only for that reason.

Comment: hmm well I just added .ljust(8,'0') right after .upper() in my op and got: 50C30000. Great! But when I do this for the number 1 I get 10000000 instead of 01000000....

Comment: the change to 'I' fixed it, works! Thanks guys! EDIT: Also removing hex() allowed it to be a viable argument for format(), thanks for that

Comment: @Ashwin: Yes, the padding of 0's is always on the left. We're not actually formatting a number as little-endian, we're byte-swapping a number then formatting it as big-endian. That means we have to swap the right number of bytes to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`ljust`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ljust)?

```
import struct
print hex( struct.unpack( '<H', struct.pack('>H', 50000) ) [0] ) [2:].upper().ljust(8, '0')
#Outputs 50C30000
```

`ljust(8,'0')` justifies the string to the left, changes the length of the string to 8 characters, and if any fill character is specified, fills the empty spaces with that character. Here the fill character is added to the `right` of the string.